# Connection via Socket.io fails

Tags: python, docker, socket.io, client, python-socketio

I am trying to connect a Client to a Server in a Docker Container using the python module socketio.

```
sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    sio.emit('connectAI', "TEST")
    print('connection established')

@sio.event
def my_message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    sio.emit('connectAI', "TEST")

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

def main():
    sio.connect('http://server:4000')
    sio.wait()

print("Setting up Connection...")
time.sleep(3)
main()
```

When I run that code, it takes about a minute before it gives me the following outputs all at once:

```
dame-ai-1      | Setting up Connection...
dame-ai-1      | disconnected from server
dame-ai-1      | disconnected from server
```

The output suggests that the socket was connected, but then after a while timed out. However, I should get a connection message and see data in the Server, but that is not the case.